# Can I use LPDDR with Cyclone III FPGA?

Tags: fpga, ddr, cyclone

I have seen the Cyclone III datasheet and it claims DDR and DDR2 compatible PHY.
But was looking some good LPDDR chips for my design. 
Could I use the PHY inside of Cyclone III with LPDDR ic?
Do you know other FPGA compatible with LPDDR?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Cyclone III will support LPDDR and LPDDR2, but you really should talk to an Altera applications engineer to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No LPDDR is not supported by Cyclone III. Neither LPDDR2. Afaik Xilinx introduced LPDDR support since Spartan-3